# Disabling MDTM commands on Windows FTP Server

Tags: windows, ftp

There is a situation where files arrival audit on FTP server needs to maintain. It works perfectly until someone from FTP client fires MDTM command to preserve their created/modified datetime.
Now question is, how can it be disable in Windows 2008 R2 Standard Server loaded with IIS7 for FTP so that Client's MDTM command can't success.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on IIS.net forum:- https://forums.iis.net/t/1237647.aspx?Disabling+MDTM+commands+on+Windows+FTP+Server

Though I need to verify it's working, I thought to post here to help others on the same issue.